# Refresh DIV on success with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, best-in-place

I have a Rails app displaying the workshifts of employees in a table. The user can edit the `shiftstart` and `shiftend` directly in the table with the [Best In Place](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place) gem.

I got the update of the database working, but the `DIV` needs to be reloaded so the bar showing the duration of the shift either expands or contracts depending on the change in the start and end time.

I guess I need some javascript to do this and it might be simple, but I can't figure it out :)

VIEW

```
<div class="shift-data">

    <% @myShifts.where(:shiftdate => date).order(:shiftstart).each do |shift| %>

        <div id="shift_<%= shift.id %>" class="shift-item span" style="width: <%= (shift.shiftend - shift.shiftstart) / 60 / 60 / 24 * 100 %>%; left: <%= shift.shiftstart.seconds_since_midnight / 60 / 60 / 24 * 100 %>%; top: 0px;">
            <div class="hider" style="background-color: #<%= shift.type.color %>;">
                <p>
                    <i class="icon gear"></i>
                    <%= best_in_place shift, :shiftstart, :type => :input, :display_with => :format_time_bip %> - <%= shift.shiftend.strftime("%H.%M") %> <span class="tag"><%= shift.type.name.upcase %></span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

    <% end %>

</div>
```

APPLICATION.JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* Activating Best In Place */
  jQuery(".best_in_place").best_in_place();
});

$(function() {
  jQuery(".best_in_place").bind("ajax:success", function() {

    /* It's here I need some help .... */

  });
});
```

EDIT:

The rendered HTML:

```
<div class="shift-data">
  <div id="shift_3" class="shift-item span" style="width: 58.333333333333336%; left: 8.333333333333332%; top: 0px;">
    <div class="hider" style="background-color: #df5c64;">
      <p>
        <i class="icon gear"></i>
        <span id="best_in_place_shift_3_shiftstart" class="best_in_place" data-original-content="2000-01-01 02:00:00 +0100" data-type="input" data-attribute="shiftstart" data-object="shift" data-url="/shifts/3">02.00</span>
        - 16.00
        <span class="tag">FERIE</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ajax success callback should give you the response of the ajax request:

```
$(function() {
  jQuery(".best_in_place").bind("ajax:success", function(data) {
    var id = $(this).data('url').split('shifts/')[1]; // Maybe you don't need this

    $('#shift_' + id).css({
        'left' : 'xx',
        'width': 'xx'
    });

  });
});
```

Comment: The callback only gives me the new value in the database for shiftstart.. I need to refresh the parent DIV somehow, so the DIV containing the bar get refreshed and shows the new duration of the shift. Make sense? :)

Comment: I need to refresh id="shift_<%= shift.id %>", but don't know how to target that specific DIV..

Comment: It would make things easier if you would include the rendered html in your question. I presume you want to update the css of div.shift-item.

Comment: Do you have more than one `div.shift-item` in your html? Do you know the id of the `div.shift-item` you want to change? I presume you want to edit the width. See my answer.

Comment: Just added the HTML to the question.. yes I have multiple shift-items and I know the ID (can I pass that to the javascript?). It not only the width that changes - also the startpoint from the left, so I think it's easier to just refresh the intire DIV container..

Comment: see, now we are talking :) that seems to work - just needed an underscore on the '#shift_' + id thing.. Thanks a lot.. happy holidays!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21596/discussion-between-tj-and-twiddr)